# How to build association between two table such that the child table will share just one field of parent table as foreign key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

There is a parent table LOT and a child table BLOCK. Now I want LOT -> lot_id as a foreign key for the BLOCK table. and there are two api calls am making to GET/POST for LOT and BLOCK.

api/park/lots and api/park/blocks

When am creating a record for BLOCK (api/park/blocks), it gets created. But when I make a api call GET (api/park/lots) through LOT, am unable to get the child (BLOCK) record

Below is the sample json

{
"lot_id": "1001",
"name": "NEWLOT",

```
"parkingBlocks": [],
"availability": {
    "available_spots": 50,
    "occupied_spots": 2,
    "unknown_spots": 0,
    "competitors": 0
}
```

}

Though I have a block of id '2001' for the lot '1001' in GET request unable to retrieve

Entity of LOT
`code`
@Id
private String lot_id;
private String name = "";

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = ParkingBlock.class,cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<ParkingBlock> parkingBlocks = new ArrayList<>();
```

Entity of BLOCK
@Id
private String block_id;

```
//THIS IS THE FOREIGN KEY I CREATED MANUALLY
@OneToOne(targetEntity = ParkingLot.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "lot_id")
private String lot_id;


@ManyToOne(targetEntity = ParkingLot.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
private ParkingLot parkingLot;

//accessors
```

`code`

The lot id is not getting saved in DB

Answer (score 0):

Consider to do this:

- Add @JoinColumn in the relationship in other to the ORM knows how can do the join between tables.
- In order to save both tables try to set in each instance of BLOCK the instance of LOT so the ORM detects that both entities are connected and do first the insert of LOT and later use the id of LOT used in the BLOCK entity